# CSS3 Transitions Not Working On Specific HREF

Tags: html, css, transition

For some reason, on this page, in Chrome 17, CSS3 transitions aren't working the first 3 links in the footer/nav: http://jacob.bearce.me/index2.htm. The links are exactly the same, no added classes, and I went through step by step to figure out what it was, it's changing the HREF property that breaks them. For some strange reason, services.htm works, but projects.htm does not. I have absolutely no idea why.

UPDATE: Tested in Firefox, Opera and Safari it seems to be only a Chrome issue. It makes no sense. It's not even a webkit issue (unless Chrome's got a newer version than Safari).

Comment: Works okay for me in Chrome 15 and Chrome 17 Canary; I see no difference in Firefox 7. Colours and text fade/slide in and out just fine.

Comment: Very strange. I still can't get it working. Maybe it's just this instance of Chrome or something, I wonder if it'd fix it if I re-installed...UPDATE: Changed some stuff in the footer, now all the links aren't fading. Still no idea why.

Comment: Could any extensions be interfering? Does viewing the page in an incognito window change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to be bug with Chrome. I've figured out that it's definitely an issue with `:visited` links, but can't fix it no matter what. In incognito mode you don't see the issue because Chrome isn't logging what links you've visited. From what I've seen, it looks like it's an issue in Chrome 16 or higher. Hopefully they'll fix this in the next release, but for now, we'll just have to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if this response is slightly late, however, I'm currently on Google Chrome 16.0.912.63 beta-m and I have the exact same problem as you do. In fact, on your website, out of the 4 links below, it is only the home link that doesn't seem to be working too well with CSS3 transitions (on my side).

On a website I'm currently working on, the transitions seems to only work on some links and not others. I can't really see any trend to understand what causes it. Strangely though, when I visit your website or mine through Incognito, everything works well. It doesn't work even with my extensions disabled.

Comment: Wow, I just happened to look at this today because I'm working on another project with the same issue. I tested the Incognito thing, too, and it's working fine for me. Very strange, and it seems to ALWAYS fix it, no matter what the project is. It's a very strange thing, and as far as I can tell, it's something to do with the HREF property. Very strange.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with visited links. Even setting `a:visited` doesn't fix it, though.

Comment: Just an update on this, the problem seems to be resolved now. I'm currently on Google Chrome 18.0.1025.54 beta-m and I don't seem to be facing the same problem anymore. They probably patched it up so good job!

Comment: Yea, it's not happening for me either, but someone I work with is having it on Chrome for Mac now. Weird little bug.